How to use custom .framework with flutter plugin
the problem is I'm getting sharing Module not found
let's say I have
sharing.framework & I have a flutter plugin + flutter project
flutter plugin is inside the flutter project, I want to use sharing.framework inside flutter plugin
I was able to use the sharing.framework inside the whole flutter project but not inside the flutter plugin (module not found)
I added the sharing.framework inside Embed Frameworks & inside Link Binary with libraries (build phases)
the sharing.framework is inside Frameworks folder,
also in my flutter plugin podspec I tried adding
# Add vendored frameworks
s.vendored_frameworks = 'ios/Frameworks/sharing.framework'

# Preserve paths
s.preserve_paths = 'ios/Frameworks/sharing.framework'

# Link the framework to your plugin
s.frameworks = 'sharing'

Please if anyone can help & tell me exactly how to make this

Any update on this?

I solved it,
edit the podspec
# Add vendored frameworks
s.vendored_frameworks = 'sharing.framework'

# Preserve paths
s.preserve_paths = 'sharing.framework'

# Link the framework to your plugin
s.frameworks = 'sharing'

& put sharing.framework inside the ios folder not inside any sub folder (classes...)
